# Accessing Page.Items in sub pages in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have some global variables that I get their value from database in Master Page. to be able to access them in all pages I add them to `Page.Items` collection. I don't use CodeBehind and all my pages are like:

```
<script runat="server">
//some variables here...
protected void Page_Load(object sender,EventArgs e){

}
</script>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="body" runat="server">
</asp:Content>
```

As the `Page_Load` function in pages are called before master page so the `Page.Items` are not yet added in `Page_Load` function of the pages but I can access them in `asp:Content` tags. where should I add to this collection in master page so that I can access these them In all parts of the Page?

Comment: Try adding it in `Init` event of Master page.

Comment: @RahulSingh I added `Init` event but its not triggering at all

Comment: @AshkanMobayenKhiabani: Why don't you use Application variable ? Save variable in it like - `Application["YourVariableName"] = 1` and then use it in app as per your requirement.

Comment: @KrishnrajRana these are not application variables for example I need to authenticate user in both master page and default.aspx I don't want to do this authentication twice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write these codes in master page (Class Name Of master page is My Master Page)

```
public bool var1
{
    get { return (bool) (ViewState["var1"] == null? false : ViewState["var1"]); }
    set { ViewState["var1"] = value; }
}

public int var2
{
    get { return (bool) (ViewState["var2"] == null? 0 : ViewState["var2"]); }
    set { ViewState["var2"] = value; }
}

 public String callMeFromAnyPageUnderMe(int num)
{
    // some code here
    num = num + 2;
    return num.ToString();
}
```

Use the variables and functions in any page that use the master page

```
MyMasterPage myMaster = Page.Master as MyMasterPage;
myMaster.var1 = true;
myMaster.var1 = 1;
myMaster.callMeFromAnyPageUnderMe(213);
```